# VBA - Maximo de caracteres no dropdown-list

Tags: vba, excel-vba, microsoft-excel

```
' Validação Motivo
Columns(motivo).Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:= _
    "TESTE1;TESTE2;TESTE3;TESTE4;TESTE5;TESTE6;TESTE7;TESTE8;TESTE9;TESTE10;TESTE11;TESTE12;TESTE13;TESTE14;TESTE15;TESTE16;TESTE17;TESTE18;TESTE19;TESTE20;TESTE21;TESTE22;TESTE23;TESTE24;TESTE25;TESTE26;TESTE27;TESTE28;TESTE29;TESTE30;TESTE31;TESTE32;TESTE33"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Se minha lista de 'testes' exceder os 256 characteres, minha lista fica bloqueada e se exceder 1024, um erro é recebido.

No exemplo acima, tenho uma lista até teste33, totalizando 256 characteres. Como eu adicionaria o teste34 e assim, contornar este erro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referindo a esta resposta do SO Global: [Maximum drop-down list/formula length in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017403/maximum-drop-down-list-formula-length-in-excel)

O passo-a-passo será explicado a seguir:

### Criar Planilha com Dados de Validação

Primeiro uma planilha deve ser criada com os dados de validação e não do modo:

`Formula1:= _
 "TESTE1;TESTE2;TESTE3;TESTE4;TESTE5;TESTE6;TESTE7;TESTE8;TESTE9;TESTE10;TESTE11;TESTE12;TESTE13;TESTE14;TESTE15;TESTE16;TESTE17;TESTE18;TESTE19;TESTE20;TESTE21;TESTE22;TESTE23;TESTE24;TESTE25;TESTE26;TESTE27;TESTE28;TESTE29;TESTE30;TESTE31;TESTE32;TESTE33"`

A Planilha de Nome `ListaValid` deve ser criada e os dados de validação colocados em alguma coluna, no exemplo na Coluna A, como na imagem:

[image: Lista de Validação]

### Código

O código abaixo insere a lista da Coluna A da planilha ListaValid como validação na coluna C da planilha Planilha1.

```
LastRow = Worksheets("ListaValid").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="List", RefersTo:="=ListaValid!$A$1:$A$" & LastRow
Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("C:C").Validation.Delete
Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("C:C").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=List"
```

Obs.: Para evitar erros de células em branco na lista de validação, uma função para deletar estes dados pode ser adicionado.

### Resultado

Um teste foi realizado com a lista de validação com dados de TESTE1 a TESTE400, ou seja, 400 linhas.

O resultado é o seguinte:

[image: Resultado]

### Explicação

#### Última linha

`LastRow = Worksheets("ListaValid").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

Achar a última linha da planilha da lista de validação e coluna A, ou seja, os dados da lista devem ser preenchidos a partir da linha 1, em ordem.

#### Criar Name List

`ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="List", RefersTo:="=ListaValid!$A$1:$A$" & LastRow`

Cria uma List com os dados da planilha de validação, no Range de A1 até A & Última Linha

#### Deletar Validação

`Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("C:C").Validation.Delete`

Deleta toda a validação da coluna C, para inserí-la na próxima linha e evitar erros.

#### Inserir Validação

`Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("C:C").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=List"`

Insere a validação com os dados da lista criada.

Comment: Daniel, obrigado pela resposta. Consegui solucionar meu problema anteriormente e foi exatamente como sua resposta.