# Validação de dados

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou a criar um ficheiro de base de dados e tenho uma validação de dados em que o modelo corresponde à respectiva marca.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu fiz uma validação de dados tipo lista a partir da tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com a seguinte fórmula:

> =SE(F6=$Q$5;$Q$6:$Q$8;SE(F6=$R$5;$R$6:$R$7;SE(F6=$S$5;$S$6:$S$7)))

Está a funcionar correctamente, se seleccionar Marca -> Citröen apenas consigo seleccionar no Modelo -> DS3 ou C3 e o mesmo para as restantes marcas.

A questão é: existe uma forma mais simples de criar a validação de dados?
É necessário abranger quase todas as marcas o que vai levar a uma extensa fórmula na validação de dados.

Obrigado.

Encontrei uma fórmula mais pequena e simples para criar a lista suspensa (peguei na sugestão do @rbz)

**Solução:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com `INDIRECTO` a ir buscar informação da respectiva Marca=Aba torna a "criação" da lista suspensa mais fácil e pratica.

Sempre que haja uma nova **Marca** teremos uma nova **Aba** e basta colocar os respectivos modelos na coluna **A** que a lista suspensa é automaticamente actualizada.

Nota: Esta solução serve para o meu projecto.

Comment: Depende muito do quanto você tem de variações, o quanto de cadastros, etc. Você poderia ter que chegar a nível de ter 1 aba por marca, com modelos, versões, e usar a `PROCV`.

Comment: @rbz, usando `PROCV` não irá indicar apenas o primeiro valor encontrado? Mas peguei na tua ideia de uma marca por aba e penso que o `INDIRECTO` com colunas de auxilio pode resolver o meu "problema".

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse [link](https://powerexcel.com.br/2018/02/21/combinando-lista-suspensa-e-procv/).

Comment: Não é isso que pretendo. O que quero é que ao preencher a ficha de cliente e indicar a marca do carro apenas me deixe seleccionar os respectivos modelos. Consegui o esperado utilizando: Abas=Marcas e dentro de cada Marca os seus modelos e usei o `INDIRECTO` e pelo que parece está a funcionar.

Comment: Como posso postar o ficheiro para verem o que queria e como resolvi?

Comment: Da forma que achar melhor, mas que, quem lê, consiga entender, simular, executar o que passar.

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei a solução. Obrigado pela disponibilidade.

Comment: Há o máximo de caracteres que uma lista de validação pode possuir. Caso isto ocorra, [vesta esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/259652/75104)

Answer (score 0):

Você tem algumas opções, você pode usar Macros para criar um Database Coerente e eficiente, porem levara um tempo para desenvolver e testar, mas é a melhor e melhor em questão de manutenção quando ficar maior o Database.

A segunda opção é criar uma lista suspensa para ter as opções de marcas e qualquer outra coluna como Modelo Ano versão, você pode ler o tutorial no próprio link da MS [Lista Suspensa](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/aplicar-valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-dados-a-c%C3%A9lulas-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249), acho mais fácil para você entender melhor as opções

A terceira você pode também usar a Função PROCV, você cria uma área com os dados e consegue realizar uma busca por qualquer categoria que tenha criado como modelo, marca, ano e etc. você pode ler o tutorial no [Funcao PROCV](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/procv-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-procv-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1), também da MS.

Agora vai da sua parte analisar qual opção é melhor, só lembrando na escalabilidade da solução, porque uma coisa é ter uma base de dados de 10 carros outra é de 10.000 carros.